# How to render two arrays in jsx

Tags: reactjs, loops, jsx

So I have two lists: `categories` and `channels` both of them have two objects. Now I want to loop through each of them but the problem is no matter how I loop through them I always end up with two results either the items are displayed 4 times (should be 2) or the nested loop (channel loop) is displaying all of its items on all the categories.

```js
     <div className="fixed inset-0 m-auto bg-[#2F3136]">
        <div>
          <h1>{server?.title}</h1>
          <ArrowDropDownOutlinedIcon />
        </div>

        {categories?.map((category) => (
          <div key={category._id}>
            <h1>{category.title}</h1>
            {channels?.map((channel) => (
              <h1>{channel.title}</h1>
            ))}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
```

Comment: So there are as many items in `categories` as in `channels`  and you want one `channel` on each `categorie` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean to loop only channels in that caterogy?
You should `filter` your channels before you loop them.

Lets say you each channel contains `category` prop which is equal to category

```
    <div className="fixed inset-0 m-auto bg-[#2F3136]">
        <div>
          <h1>{server?.title}</h1>
          <ArrowDropDownOutlinedIcon />
        </div>

        {categories?.map((category) => (
          <div key={category._id}>
            <h1>{category.title}</h1>
            {channels?.filter((channel)=>channel.category===category)
.map((channel) => (
              <h1>{channel.title}</h1>
            ))}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! Just had to make the ids match each other

Answer (score 0):

The thing is on each iteration of map, it is expecting some output to be returned that it can display on the screen, Now if there is a loop inside it you need to explicitly tell map to return what and what on the end of each iteration with return (). Here is the example (You need to wrap it inside an element like return () i mean or <></> etc):
Make sure you are returning the second map itself and not just the final expected output:

```
        <tbody>
          {Object.keys(templates).map(function (template_name) {
            return (
              <tr key={template_name}>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <b>Template: {template_name}</b>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                {templates[template_name].items.map(function (item) {
                  return (
                    <tr key={item.id}>
                      <td>{item}</td>
                    </tr>
                  );
                })}
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
```